# multiple inner routes in Camel Spring

Tags: java, spring, jackson, apache-camel, pojo

I'm stuck with camel documentation as it's not very clear...

I want to define this route in Spring :

```
in: direct access from a url
out: get an object instance from a factory
--> format this object in Json
```

I've tried with marshaller like this :

```
<camel:route id="viewObject">
  <camel:from uri="restlet:/json/" />

  <camel:to uri="bean:myFactory" />
  <camel:unmarshal ref="jack" />
</camel:route>
```

but it doesn't work as the unmarshal works after input and before output, this was expected so I tried to re route the output to another endpoint.

```
<camel:route id="formatObject">
  <camel:from uri="bean:myFactory" />
  <camel:unmarshal ref="jack" />
  <camel:to uri="mock:reverse" />
</camel:route>
```

Basically I want my object :

```
public class MyObject{
  private String name;
  [ getter & setter here]
 }
```

to be unmarshalled this way :

```
 {name : 'a value'}
```

And this only with marshaller and camel config.
Please help, crystal clear explanations and howtos are welcomed too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, just create xml like this inside your camel context.

```
<dataFormats>
  <json id="jack" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.example.MyObject"/>
</dataFormats>

<route>
        <from uri="restlet:/json/"/>
        <to uri="bean:myFactory"/>
        <marshal ref="jack"/>
</route>
```

You seem to have mixed up the marshall/unmarshall words

Unmarshall = from json -> bean
Marshall = from bean -> json.